# JsViews vs AngularJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, angularjs, single-page-application, jsviews

I intend to develop single page application. jsViews/jsRender looks very promising and it is almost reaching Beta. Since I am new to SPA development I am curious to know how jsViews compares to other SPA frameworks such as AngularJS in terms of e.g. speed, functionality or usability?

Thanks!

Comment: Compares those criteria in what way, what have you tried / researched so far?

Comment: The [ToDoMVC project](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) solves the ToDo app using different MV frameworks. This website is useful for comparing different styles used in each framework. However, jsViews is not yet listed but there exists a todo example on [githup](http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/step-by-step/10_todos.html) which can be used for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have very different approaches. i recommend researching both if your intent is to compare them. The best choice is to find a framework or set of libraries that work for you and run with it. There is no "best".